# MATLAB contourf plot for an irregular domain

Tags: matlab, polygon, contour

I am stuck with this problem for a long time now. I have a polygonal region (lets say, a hexagon). I can calculate the values of certain function at any point inside the polygon. Now I need to create a filled contour (using contourf in MATLAB) of this data. How do I go about it. I found some discussion on this topic at the link below (page 121)

http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jpboyd/eng403_chap4_contourplts.pdf

This works somewhat ok but it still produces jagged edges which I don't want. Anyone has any suggestion on this problem? Thanks. Here is my code

```
close all
Node  = [ 1.0  0
          0.5  0.8660
         -0.5  0.8660
         -1.0  0
         -0.5 -0.8660
          0.5 -0.8660];
[x,y] = meshgrid(-1:0.1:1,-1:0.1:1);

N = zeros(size(x));
for i=1:size(x,2)
    for j=1:size(y,2)
        p = [x(i,j) y(i,j)];
        IN = inpolygon(p(1),p(2),Node(:,1),Node(:,2));
        if IN
            N(i,j)= rand;            
        else
            N(i,j)= NaN;
        end
    end
end

figure
contourf(x,y,N,'LineStyle','none'), hold on;     
xlabel('X'), ylabel('Y'), axis equal; axis off; colorbar;    
line([Node(:,1);Node(1,1)],[Node(:,2);Node(1,2)],'Color',[1 1 1],'LineWidth',2.0)
clear IN i j p x y
```

Comment: Can we see your code and some of the data you are working with?

Answer (score 0):

You're using a square grid to sample a hexagonal area. This will indeed lead to boundary problems.

A better solution (but still not quite optimal) is to use a [hexagonal grid](http://matlabdatamining.blogspot.nl/2008/04/generating-hexagonal-grids-for-fun-and.html):

```
%# define hexagon
Node  = [ 1.0  0
          0.5  0.8660
         -0.5  0.8660
         -1.0  0
         -0.5 -0.8660
          0.5 -0.8660];

%# Generate hexagonal grid
Rad3Over2 = sqrt(3) / 2;
[x, y] = meshgrid(0:51);
n = size(y,1);
x = Rad3Over2 * x;
y = y + repmat([0 0.5],[n,n/2]);

%# re-scale to -1..1
x = 2*x/max(x(:))-1;
y = 2*y/max(y(:))-1;

%# insode-polygon check 
N = zeros(size(x));
for i=1:size(x,2)
    for j=1:size(y,2)
        p = [x(i,j) y(i,j)];
        IN = inpolygon(p(1),p(2),Node(:,1),Node(:,2));
        if IN
            N(i,j)= rand;            
        else
            N(i,j)= NaN;
        end
    end
end

%# make contour plot
figure(1)
contourf(x,y,N,'LineStyle','none'), hold on;     
xlabel('X'), ylabel('Y'), axis equal; axis off; colorbar;    
line([Node(:,1);Node(1,1)],[Node(:,2);Node(1,2)],'Color',[1 1 1],'LineWidth',2.0)
```

If you want even better coverage, you'll have to devise a grid that better covers your area and/or up the number of sample points.

For arbitrary irregular areas, you might want to experiment with irregular/random grids, distributed such that there are more points close to the boundaries, than there are in the middle of the area.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I was also thinking along the same direction. The boundary of the polygon needs to be incorporated into the grid somehow. Being close to the boundary is not enough. The contour plot will still be jagged. I am looking for some other more intuitive approach to plot contours of general shapes.

Comment: An interesting problem, no doubt. I'll try to look into it some more.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a function defined on a hexagon. Then take some square that contains the hexagon.

A simple first test could be to extend your function on the square to take the value = 0 for points outside of the hexagon.

Depending on the range of your function this may, or may not, give you a good answer.

If this doesn't work, then find the min of the function on the hexagon using `min(min(A)))` for an nxn matrix A.  Then define the function to be `min(min(A)) - 1.0` outside of the hexagon but in the square.

Then use `contourf(x, y, z, v)` where v is a vector of values for the output, so take `v(1) = min(min(A)) - 1.0`, and `v(2:n) = linspace(min(min(A)), max(max(A)), n)` for some integer n.  You can probably specify the color of the level set `min(min(A)) - 1.0` to be white, but I've never done this.  I've had to do something like this before, and setting the function = 0 outside of he hexagon was enough.

Comment: I had tried these before using NaN for points outside the region of interest. Using NaN, makes MATLAB ignore those points when plotting which is what I want. If you assign any value other than NaN to the outside points, those points still show up in the contour plot and also result in jagged edges.

Comment: I did something like what I suggested, it worked for me...Maybe you're grid isn't fine enough? What I described worked when I applied a function on a fine grid to an oval shaped region. Also, when you assigned other non NaN values, did you (1) make sure the value was less than the min of the function on the hexagon and (2) specify which contours you want plotted, as I suggested in the last two paragraphs of my answer? That would certainly help to distinguish between the outside and inside of the hexagon.  It could also be that I was lucky with my example and the method is not robust...

Answer (score 0):

If your function can only be evaluated *inside* the polygonal region, then my hexagonal grid answer still stands. However, if your function can be (or modified to be) evaluated *outside* the polygon, you might want to use a cheat:

```
figure(1), clf, hold on

%# External contour, square.
x1 = [-3 -3 +3 +3 -3]/2;
y1 = [-3 +3 +3 -3 -3]/2;

%# internal contour, some polygon 
x2  = [1.0 0.5 -0.5 -1.0 -0.5 0.5];
y2 = [0 0.8660 0.8660 0 -0.8660 -0.8660];

%# convert to patches
[f, v] = poly2fv({x1, x2}, {y1, y2});
patch(...
    'Faces'    , f,...
    'Vertices' , v,...
    'FaceColor', get(0, 'defaultuicontrolbackgroundcolor'), ...
    'EdgeColor', 'none'...
    );

%# Generate function for contourplot
[x, y] = meshgrid(-2.8/2:0.1:2.8/2);
N = rand(size(x));

%# make contour plot
contourf(x,y,N,'LineStyle','none'), hold on;     
xlabel('X'), ylabel('Y'), axis equal; 
axis off; colorbar;
```

It basically creates your contour plot on a square region, and overlays a mask with a hexagonal hole in it, so it *looks like* it's only a contour of the hexagonal. I suspect it is a lot easier to tweak your function to allow function evaluations outside the region, then it is to (re-)invent some sort of grid that contains the boundaries.